# Add Google Map By Address

Tags: plugin-recommendation, map

Is there a plugin that allowed me to add google map embed code by only supplying address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[5secGoogleMaps by WebFactory is a very promising one](http://codecanyon.net/item/5sec-google-maps/152372?ref=mordauk).

You enter a map like this:

```
[gmap]your address[/gmap]
```

Comment: That looks awesome

Answer (score 1):

Map Press would work, but you have to enter each address  individually and then it generates a short code that you insert into a post/page

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mappress-google-maps-for-wordpress/

Comment: Map press includes a template tag, so if your using it , you just had to hit "save".